# How to check if a Kconfig string is empty using Zephyr?

Tags: c-preprocessor, kbuild, zephyr-rtos

Given this Kconfig:

```
config MY_STR
    string "A string"
```

The directive `#if defined(CONFIG_MY_STR)` will eval to true for the default empty string.

How to check if *CONFIG_MY_STR* is an empty string at compile time? Is it a better practice to use a second boolean value (e.g. *CONFIG_USE_MY_STR*) like the following?

```
config MY_STR
    string "A string"
    depends on USE_MY_STR

config USE_MY_STR
    bool "Enable MY_STR"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [string symbols implicitly default to the empty string](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/guides/kconfig/tips.html#redundant-defaults) the [BUILD_ASSERT()](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/reference/kernel/other/fatal.html) can be used to perform compile time check:

```
BUILD_ASSERT(1 != sizeof(CONFIG_SOMEPROPERTY), "SOMEPROPERTY required");
```

And pass it during the build like

```
west build -- -DCONFIG_SOMEPROPERTY=\"1.0\" [other arguments]
```